# Uncheck checked radio button by clicking on label using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I need to uncheck checked radio buttons using jQuery. The buttons themselves are hidden so I am using clicks on the labels to trigger this. So far I have:

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <h4>Where would you like to work?</h4>
  <div class="radio-holder">
    <input id="form1_areas1" name="areas" type="radio" value="area/london">
    <label for="form1_areas1">London</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-holder">
    <input id="form1_areas2" name="areas" type="radio" value="area/west-midlands">
    <label for="form1_areas2">West Midlands</label></div>
</form>
```

**SCSS**

```
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
div.radio-holder {
  padding: 10px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
 display:none;
 &:checked+label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
 }
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form input[type='radio']:checked + label").click(function(){
    $(this).prev().prop( "checked", false );
  });
});
```

Here a **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/jaVGzj)**

But this isn't unchecking the radio button. I understand this is not standard functionality for radio buttons, but I need the user to be able to revert the set of radio buttons to their unselected state if desired, while also limiting them to selecting one from the set of options. Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Mike

Comment: check this  :  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeBexV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable/disable same radio , You have to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent default behavior ( enabling check box when clicking on label, so checked prop will be always set to true ) and make radio enable / disable grammatically as shown in the below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("label").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $check = $(this).prev();
    if($check.prop('checked'))
      $check.prop( "checked", false );
    else 
      $check.prop( "checked", true );
      
    //console.log($check.prop("checked"));
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
div.radio-holder {
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
 display:none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h4>Where would you like to work?</h4>
  <div class="radio-holder">
    <input id="form1_areas1" name="areas" type="radio" value="area/london">
    <label for="form1_areas1">London</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-holder">
    <input id="form1_areas2" name="areas" type="radio" value="area/west-midlands">
    <label for="form1_areas2">West Midlands</label></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use next trick:
-Add a `data-num` attribute.
-Play with `data-num` on each click to check/uncheck the radio buttons.
Hope it helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").click(function(){
       $("input").not(this).attr("data-num", 1); 
       var data = $(this).attr("data-num")
       if(data==1){
          data = 2
          $(this).attr("data-num", data); 
          return;
       }
       if(data==2){
          data = 1
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
          $(this).attr("data-num", data); 
          return;
       }
  })  
})
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
div.radio-holder {
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
 display:none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222222;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h4>Where would you like to work?</h4>
  <div class="radio-holder">
    <input id="form1_areas1" name="areas" type="radio" value="area/london" data-num="1">
    <label for="form1_areas1">London</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-holder">
    <input id="form1_areas2" name="areas" type="radio" value="area/west-midlands" data-num="1">
    <label for="form1_areas2">West Midlands</label></div>
</form>
```